# If $y=\frac{1}{3u}\frac{du}{dx}$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Tags: derivatives

If $y=\frac{1}{3u}\frac{du}{dx}$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

My thoughts:

Differentiating with respect to x gives:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3u}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{3u^2}\frac{du}{dx}$

However, it should be:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3u}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{3u^2}(\frac{du}{dx})^2$

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Yes, the extra du/dx comes from chain rule on u.

Comment: Ah yes, obvious now that you say it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{1}{3u}\frac{du}{dx}$$
D.w.t. $x$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1}{3u^2}\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3u}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$
When you differentiate $u$, $du/dx$ will multiply.

Comment: Oh! yes thanks.